# Pyparsing will always insert a list on 'setParseAction'

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

Apparently if you add any parse action and return a result in that action, the result will always be encapsulated into a list 'deepening' the output tree.

I suppose this is for returning multiple values but it makes casual use of the library far harder because you then have to remember which parts of the tree you replaced and call `result.normalstruct.replaced[0]` (or even worse `result.normalstruct['replaced'][0]`)

This is a bit strange and makes refactoring harder, so i'd like a way to avoid it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the **argument** token of `setParseAction` is already a list. Instead of operating on `str(token_argument)` i should operate on `str(token_argument[0])` and return that. No more deepening.

edit: though apparently it doesn't happen always. Happened to me with a word action but when i tried to 'unwrap' element zero of a 'And' expression result from a setParseAction functor it gave me the first subexpression.

Man, i'd like consistency here.